# PHPで値を JSON 形式で表示したい場合、 header('content-type: application/json;')は必要？

Tags: php, json

**やりたいこと**
・PHPで値を JSON 形式で表示したい

---

**現状**

```
print json_encode("日本語");
```

---

**質問**
・この時、下記コードも必要でしょうか？

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

・必要
・合った方が良い
・なくても良い
・不要

Answer (score 9, accepted):

必要です。

JSONの仕様は[RFC4627として公開](http://www.kanzaki.com/memo/2006/07/29-1)されていて、JSONテキストのMIMEタイプは`application/json`と定められています。

また、ヘッダーを設定しない場合には[JSONの直接ブラウジングによるXSS](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/ockeghem/20110907/p1)の危険性も考えられます。

Comment: 特にPHPの場合デフォルトで `Content-Type: text/html` が出力されるので、「ContentTypeを出力しない」ということは「`text/html`であると明示する」ことになります。 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1414329