# Content-Typeが違うための副作用などありますか。

Tags: html, json

例えばContent-Typeがtext/plainやtext/htmlなのにBodyはJSONのレスポンスを返した場合の副作用などはあるのでしょうか。例えばJavaScriptで読み込めないとか、読み込めたとしても処理が重くなったりするのでしょうか。

Comment: 重複候補: [PHPで値を JSON 形式で表示したい場合、 header('content-type: application/json;')は必要？](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12753/php%e3%81%a7%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92-json-%e5%bd%a2%e5%bc%8f%e3%81%a7%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e5%a0%b4%e5%90%88-headercontent-type-application-json%e3%81%af%e5%bf%85%e8%a6%81)

Comment: 実際に試してみたところ、普通に取得できました。text/htmlのコンテンツをjQuery,ajaxで取得してみました。しかし上記サイトで解説されているような脆弱性が存在するのでしっかりと対策をするべきでしょう。